# Is it true that UFOs or extraterrestrial beings that are not seen by human eyes can be captured by photo?

Tags: astrophotography

I heard that if we take photos of the sky then we can get photos of UFOs or extraterrestrial beings. Is it true ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about pseudoscience, not photography.

Comment: Maybe try http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 6):

Buy 6 x 4K Video Cams with the widest Angled Lens you can find.

Install the largest Memory card in each.

Position 3 cameras on separate tripods pointing to different sectors of the sky ensuring that the whole sky is covered, and then leave them recording.

Be ready to have a further 3 tripods with 3 cameras ready to replace the first 3 when the memory reaches max.

Then, hire a team of people to sit, without blinking in front of their monitors to watch the recorded videos! You don’t want them to miss anything!

Repeat the process  for 24hours a day, 7 days a week and 52 weeks a year!

If one of your team happens to stumble on something intriguing, capture a frame, and then send it to the Photo.stackexchange Community and we will be very interested!

I hope you appreciate the monumental task and the cost of trying to capture something that not even SETI or NASA has any verifiable evidence of!

Answer (score 3):

Since UFO's (in the sense of vehicles of extraterrestrials) and extraterrestrial beings are not confirmed to exist, there can't exist verified photos of them.

Since no verified photo of them has been made yet, we have no basis for the hypothesis that they can be photographed, especially when they can't be seen by the human eye.

Answer (score 3):

Some cameras receive wavelengths that are invisible to human eye.
If, for example, you take a photo at night, using thermal camera, and capture a passing bat or bird, but you don't know what it is, you have a photo of the unidentified flying object (UFO) that can't be seen by human eyes (because it's dark).

Comment: So UFOs release heat ?

Comment: @pheromix animal UFOs certainly do - I don't know about the outer space ones ;-)